# global variable in a .so library

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

Say library `x.so` has a global variable `y` which is being manipulated by a function(say `fun1`) in the library.

When a process `p1` is loaded into RAM whose code is using function `fun1` from library `x.so`, the library x.so will be loaded into RAM (if not already present) by ld.so and the function symbol gets resolved before the program starts executing.

Now where is this global variable created. Is it in process `p1` ?

What happens when another process `p2` also uses `fun1` (which is making operations on `y`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Processes will get their private copies of `y` and it will be replaced by a fresh copy when you call `exec`. It will reside in the library's data segment.

Comment: So when ever ld.so sees that current program is using a function from a library, it creates a fresh copy of variables in library's data segment into the current process's own data segment? Also if there is an exec() call the whole ld.so symbol resolving starts with the new code?

Comment: The library's data segment is created straight away when the library is loaded. It is created in a similar fashion as your executable's globals (as a private copy-on write file-backed VM mapping). Unlike function symbols - symbols to data are resolved straight away. When `exec` is called your entire process VM is replaced with a fresh one and all libraries are remapped from scratch.

Comment: @SergeyL, if you do an `exec()` style call, conceptually the whole memory area of the process is duplicated, so the child gets a fresh copy. In practice, to make it efficient, the operating system just gives them access to a shared reado-only copy, and duplicates only on write (copy-on-write). No remapping involved.

Comment: @vonbrand No, this is the behaviour for `fork`, `exec` replaces the process image with a new (normally different) one.

Comment: @SergeyL, you are totally right. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Each process creates its own instance of variable `y` when load library at startup before reaching `main` entry point.